# How to show confirmation message before "removedfile" event is raised, in dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

In `dropzone`, the `removedfile` event is raised after the remove button has been clicked and therefore not suitable for showing a confirmation message to user before the image is removed. Is there any other event that can be handled to show a confirmation message to the user before deleting the image?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is somewhat an old question, but I've just got the same problem and I want to share the solution I found if anyone need it. If you set the `dictRemoveFileConfirmation` on your dropzone's option, it will automatically ask for confirmation before the file is removed from the queue.

[same issue here](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/814)

Comment: Wow, this is really an unfortunate API.  There really should be a `removeFile` callback that allows you to customize the workflow.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done.  It's awkward, kludgy and involves a bit of a hack.  The API really wasn't built for it.

As mentioned by @dapidmini, you need to set `dictRemoveFileConfirmation` to a non-null value.  This enables the process you're looking for.  Keep reading.

Once you assign `dictRemoveFileConfirmation`, all you're going to get is an ugly javascript modal yes/no dialog, which is called by `Dropzone.confirm(...)`.  **Not good.**

Here's the snippet of source from Dropzone that starts the process, from the `removeFileEvent` callback.  I've added my comments...

```
// if dictRemoveFileConfirmation is set, it will invoke Dropzone.confirm
if (_this.options.dictRemoveFileConfirmation) {
    return Dropzone.confirm(_this.options.dictRemoveFileConfirmation, function () {
        return _this.removeFile(file);
    });
} else {
    return _this.removeFile(file);
}
```

So the hack begins by re-assigning the `Dropzone.confirm` callback to **your own** callback.

E.g.

```
...
Dropzone.confirm = function(question, fnAccepted, fnRejected) {

}
...
```

If you are using something like Bootstrap, you could re-assign the above method, and launch the bootstrap modal to provide some decent visuals.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // get the dropzone reference
  let dropzone = $(".dropzone")[0].dropzone;
  // enable the removal option
  dropzone.options.addRemoveLinks = true;
  // enable the confirmation
  dropzone.options.dictRemoveFileConfirmation = "Do you really really really want to remove this?";
  let removeCallback = undefined;
  // add some files to the dropzone
  let autoExec = { name: 'autoexec.bat', size: 99999 };
  let configSys = { name: 'config.sys', size: 99999};
  dropzone.emit("addedfile", autoExec);
  dropzone.emit("complete", autoExec);
  dropzone.emit("addedfile", configSys);  
  dropzone.emit("complete", configSys);
  
  // override the removal callback behavior
  Dropzone.confirm = function(question, fnAccepted, fnRejected) {
    // retain the callback to invoke to accept the removal
    removeCallback = fnAccepted;
    // launch your fancy bootstrap modal    
    $("#js-modal").modal('show');
  };
  // listen to the click of #js-remove.  remove the item by calling removeCallback and then close the modal
  $("#js-remove").click(function() {
    if (removeCallback) {
      removeCallback();
    }
    $("#js-modal").modal('hide');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>

<div class="dropzone" action="put-your-upload-url-here">
</div>

<div id="js-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to remove this?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="js-remove" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: You could use the dictRemoveFileConfirmation option. Please note that this will use the ugly JS alert dialog box.

For example:

```
new Dropzone("#dropzone_container", {
        autoDiscover: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        maxFiles: 10,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        //The addRemoveLinks option will use the following option for wording of the Confirmation message
        dictRemoveFileConfirmation:  "Are you sure?"
});
```

**Option 2**: If you override removedFile function, you can add customised script to confirm deletion as the file preview won't be automatically removed.

For example:

```
new Dropzone("#dropzone_container", {
        autoDiscover: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        maxFiles: 10,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        removedfile: function (file) {

               //This is where you can add custom script to confirm deletion; 
               //You could use Sweetalert 2 or whatever you prefer than the ugly JS ugly alert box

               //This will manually removed the file
               file.previewElement.remove();
        }
);
```

For further readings, DropzoneJS documentation click [here](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/configuration-options).